# ClassCastException while converting LinkedHashMap to generic class

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, spring-kafka, linkedhashmap

Consider the following class :

```
public class MsgReceiver<MSG> extends AbstractMsgReceiver<MSG> implements 
MsgReceiver<MSG> {

@KafkaListener( // necessary properties )
public void receiveMessage(@Headers Map<String, Object> headers, @Payload ConsumerRecord<String, 
Object> payload) {

    super.receiveMessage(headers,(MSG) (payload.value())); // line foobar
}
```

The `payload.value()` is of type `LinkedHashMap` and when I use this class, MSG can be any of my custom POJO class. I get `ClassCastException` when converting from `LinkedMashMap` to my POJO class on line foobar. How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Why do you expect that to work?

Comment: I do not expect that to work, I tried to use ObjectMapper but even that throws error.

Comment: What does ObjectMapper have to do with this? You have a List with entries. You cannot cast a List to some POJO. What are the List's elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try using jackson mapper, or any mapper I'd say. I have been using jackson mapper for kafka queue listeners, works perfectly
Find details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

payload.value() returns iterator object. It might be the issue in typecasting. Check your POJO class for it.